# How best to modify colliders to affect pickup area for character?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, coding-efficiency

I am making a simple inventory/equipment system with a basic square character.  One of the items you can use is a potion that will increase the pickup item area.  I have a way to do this already, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

**WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE**

I have a collider on my character object, which deals with collisions with the walls and general world (all this handled in the Player script).
I then have an empty gameObject child of this object, which has a collider component the same size as the other collider (at start).
The child gameObject has a script (PickupAreaModifier script) with a OnTriggerEnter2D function that calls a method in the main character script to add the item.
If the item is the potion, then the Player script calls a method in the PickupAreaModifier script to change the size of that collider.

**WHAT I WANT**

This current logic works, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to handle this, especially considering the OnTriggerEnter2D function needing to be called on the child gameObject script.  Is there any way I can handle this in only the Player script?

Thank you in advance, I hope that makes sense!

Comment: If your worried about efficiency your fine. Its just a simple function that gets called once or twice. If your worried about how clean your code is I also don't really see an issue for a small project. But if you want an alternative way I would probably have something like a BoostController/PickupController script somewhere. Then on your PickUpArea object I'd have a simple script that detects collisions and sends the info the BoostController/PickupController which then decides what to do with it (i.e. increase the pickup area size for instance). Its good to not cram everything into 1 script.